# The English and Foreign Language University

Tags: definite-article

I would like to know whether it is English and Foreign Languages University or The English and Foriegn Languages University. because some universities are called with the article' The ' and some other universities are called without the article ' The '  For example Cambridge and Oxford University ,Andhra University and Osmania University but the university of Cambridge

One of the professors of English commented that The English and Foreign Languages University should be called Engish and Foreign Languaged University because English is a Language. I would like to know the rules regarding the 
use of the article  ' The ' before the names of Universities.

I would be most grateful to you if you could answer my question.

Comment: There are many universities which are referred to with
expressions including 'of', and these have the definite article, for
example:the University of Wales; but if abbreviated there is no
article: UCLA (the University of California at Los Angeles). Many
universities have both possibilities: London University, the
University of London (which is the official name).

Comment: "one of the professors" should not be professing. The entire phrase: English and Foreign Languages University is off-kilter. Cambridge University and Oxford University do not take **the**. UCLA, no the in the title. Some do.

Comment: @Lambie could you please tell me the universities using the article the?

Comment: The University of Chicago. Many other US state universities. The English and Foreign Languages University is using those terms as adjectives, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few if any rules in creating a name.  Organizations are essentially free to call themselves anything they want.  If a school wants to call itself "The School of Hard Knocks," that's its name; likewise if it wants to call itself "Your Favorite School," "School of Learning," "Seventeen Schools in One," or virtually anything else.

In other words, the only way to answer the question, "how should we call this school," is to ask the people who run the school.

If you go to this school's website (https://www.efluniversity.ac.in/), right at the top of the page you'll see, "THE ENGLISH AND FOREIGN LANGUAGES UNIVERSITY"

Comment: The reason is this: It uses English and Foreign Languages as adjectives, so yes, it would take the.